# Handling a UIBarButtonItem from a UITabBarController (UITabBarControllerDelegate)

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I'm new to this :-(.

I have a pretty standard Tab Bar Controller to which I've added a UIButtonBarItem (I used the storyboard editor to do this). It all looks fine, but I don't know how to handle the "button press" event. I have established a delegate for the tab bar controller, so I can capture the "didSelectViewController" events (not that it seems to help :-).

I think I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally stumbled across the solution:

1. Set up a delegate for the TabBarController ()
2. Create a method on the delegate to handle the action: -(IBAction) someHandler:(id) sender;
3. Drag a Bar Button Item into the "Navigation Bar" of the common Tab Bar Controller
4. Select the bar button, control-drag to the "First Responder" and select the "someHandler" method.

That's it, not that hard, should have figured it out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The Tab Bar Controller automatically creates buttons when you connect other views to that one.  I had this same problem using storyboard editor even though you can put it in there I believe it won't allow you to use it.  I think even just setting up an IBOutlet won't work.

In the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html

Apple specifically talks about how you just create the views and the buttons are automatically handled for you.

Otherwise if you want a tab button that doesn't bring up a new view (thats what I wanted), supposedly that doesn't fit in with Apple's design principles for what a Tab controller is.

Comment: I don't think I was very clear, I'm not referring to the "tab buttons" at the bottom, I have created a button at the top nav bar. It doesn't navigate to another view, it just triggers some processing. Each of my tab views just gives another view of the data, so you can press that button regardless of what view (tab) you are on. Does that make sense?

Comment: oh, sure. In the storyboard view you can just ctrl drag the button (in the split view) into your header file and create an Action connection like so:  http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/10/28/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/ Does that help?